# Unicode to integer with preceding zeros in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python. I am using python 2.7 version I have two unicode string variables,
`a = u'0125'`, `b = u'1234'`
Now i want to convert this variables into integer and append it into a List like `[0125, 1234]`. This is my expected output.

I have tried to convert these variables into integer and appended it into the List and got the output as `[125, 1234]`. Preceeding zero is missing in that value. Can someone give better solution for this?.

Comment: You can't have integers with leading zeros.

Comment: If you are using the integers later in a string, find the longest and put zeros in front of the ones that are shorter than the longest. What does your program require?

Comment: What i am actually doing is i have stored some data in database like [0125, 1234]. With that by appending the above two unicode variables in a list i am trying to fetch the matching records.

Comment: If you are looking for matches, you can do `if int(match) in data:` or just keep them all strings if it is possible.

Comment: Thank you, Clayton. Kept as strings and got the expected matches too.